# Can't seem to print my string out

Tags: c++

So this is a fragment of my code:

```
    void reverse(string query, string reverseQuery) {
        unsigned int i;

        for(i=0; i<query.length(); i++) {
            reverseQuery[i] = query[query.length()-1-i];
        }
        cout << reverseQuery << endl;
        return;
    }
```

The headers for iostream, string and using namespace std were also included in the code. The problem I am facing is that when I try to output the string  reverseQuery nothing comes out. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As a possible hint for your problem though: What is the initial size of `reverseQuery`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just noticed that `reversQuery` exposes that problem :-)

Comment: not related to the question, but you probably want to pass the `reverseQuery` by reference, otherwise the function is a NOOP (apart from the not working cout)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks! Resizing the reverseQuery seemed to work. As for the passing by reference initially the function was supposed to pass a string back but I was tinkering with it to see if changing it to void would help to solve the problem so I forgot to change the parameter

Comment: _"The headers for iostream, string and using namespace std were also included in the code"_ Then show that, in a [MCVE]. Why omit them? What if you made a mistake in those lines that affected the outcome? You deliberately took away from us the ability to check that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment should look like:

```
std::string reverse(const string& query) {
    std::string reverseQuery(query.length(),0); // <<<<< Ensure that the size is the same
    for(unsigned i=0; i<query.length(); i++) {
        reverseQuery[i] = query[query.length()-1-i];
    }
    // cout << reverseQuery << endl;
    return reverseQuery;
}
```

---

The way shorter and idiomatic code to achieve that with a standard c++ string is

```
std::string reverseQuery(query);
std::reverse(std::begin(reverseQuery),std::end(reverseQuery));
```

Comment: And get rid of that `cout` line. Do it at the callsite if needs be but a function called `reverse` has no business outputting anything to STDOUT. In fact, why the by-reference argument? Just return the result.

Comment: @Lighness Does that advice go to the OP, or did you really adress me? Edited my answer though.

Comment: Bit of both I suppose.

Comment: the cout was put there originally by me for debugging was checking if the problem was within this function or somewhere else in my code